# Numbers before line in c++

Tags: c++

So I am basically a complete beginner in c++ and code in general. I wrote a simple program that tells you whether or not you are male or tall from user input.

The problem is that the final if statement that takes the booleans from the function and writes a message is outputting a number beginning with 0 and then the actual message.

Like so

**"0You are a male and tall"**
or
**"01You aren't a male but tall"**

The number before seems to change depending on the user input which leads me to believe its indexing it somehow.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

    bool isMale() {

        char gender_input;
        bool genderismale;
        cout <<"Enter \"Y\" for YES and \"N\" for NO - Are you a male?: " << endl;
        cin >> gender_input;

        if (gender_input == 'Y'){ 
            genderismale = true;
        } else if (gender_input == 'N') {
            genderismale = false;
        } else{
            cout << "You entered an invalid answer! Try again! -  Y for Yes and N for No" << endl;
            cout << isMale();
        }

        return genderismale;
    }

        bool isTall() {
            
            char height_input;
            bool heightistall;
            cout <<"Enter \"Y\" for YES and \"N\" for NO - Are you over 6 feet tall?: " << endl;
            cin >> height_input;

            if (height_input == 'Y'){
                heightistall = true;
            } else if (height_input == 'N'){
                heightistall = false;
            } else {
                cout <<"You entered an invalid answer! Try again! -  Y for Yes and N for No"<< endl;
                cout << isTall();
            }

            return heightistall;
    }


int main()
{

    bool ismale = isMale();
    bool istall = isTall();

    cout << ismale;
    cout << istall;

    if(ismale && istall){
        cout << "You are a male and tall";
    } else if(ismale && !istall) {
        cout << "You are a male but not tall";
    } else if(!ismale && istall) {
        cout << "You aren't a male but tall"; 
    } else if(!ismale && !istall) {
        cout << "You aren't a male and not tall";
    }


    return 0;

}
```

**So my question is how can I remove these numbers or indexes before the desired output?**

Comment: Erm... don't print it? You clearly have 2 line `cout << ismale; cout << istall;`.

Comment: Also: `cout << isTall();` in `isTall()` is big smell

Comment: Just replace ```cout << isMale();```with ```isMale()``` and do the same for isTall.